# Value of last used route in react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In my app I need to add a condition before using navigate(-1).

Is it possible in React-Router-DOM v6 to access the previous route value?

I know that I could create history array by myself and add current pathname after each navigation,
but I wonder if it is already provided by react router

Comment: for now I could use document.referrer .. but I want to know if I could directly access the full history since the user accessed my app (SPA) without refreshing it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.